Node js multiple requests concurrently
When multiple users are concurrently accessing this API, the response is getting mixed up. User-1 is getting user-2's response.
I believe this is happening due to something I am globally using in the below code.
Please help me sort this out.
const codeModel = async (req, res) => {
  let connection;
  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection("MS");
    let lastCodeSQL = `perfectly running sql query with properly binding params)`;
    let bind = [
      req.header.USERNAME,
      req.body.C_ID,
      req.body.S_ID,
      req.body.Q_ID,
    ];
    const lastCodeSQLres = await connection.execute(lastCodeSQL, bind);
    res.json(lastCodeSQLres);
    connection.release();
  } catch (err) {
    logger.info(err);
  } finally {
    try {
      if (connection) {
        await connection.close(); // Ensure connection release
      }
    } catch (err) {
      logger.error("Error closing connection:", err);
    }
  }
};

i have the below code in my application. Is there any scope of variables being global ?
let bind = {
           userid: {
            dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
            val: username.toLowerCase(),
            type: oracledb.STRING,
          },
          c_id: {
            dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
            val: cont,
            type: oracledb.NUMBER,
          },
          q_id: {
            dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
            val: quest,
            type: oracledb.STRING,
          },
          a_q: {
            dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
            val: sql,
            type: oracledb.STRING,
          },
          q_output: {
            dir: oracledb.BIND_IN,
            val: JSON.stringify(something),
            type: oracledb.STRING,
          },
        };

Here is my middleware.
let authentication=req.headers.authtoken; 
const data=jsonwebtoken.verify(authentication,authString); 
req.header.USERNAME = data.user.EMAIL;


Can you be more clear what you mean by 'User' here. Are you making multiple concurrent requests in the same session? Even that seems unlikely to result in the behaviour you describe, though

No, multiple concurrent requests are from different sessions. User-1 and user-2 uses their own browsers to open this app. User-2's data is sent back to User-1 when they concurrently access the API.

How do you fill req.header.USERNAME?

It is filled by middleware.
let authentication=req.headers.authtoken;
const data=jsonwebtoken.verify(authentication,authString);
req.header.USERNAME = data.user.EMAIL;

I suggest you edit your question and include this middleware in it.

Indeed there is

something I am globally using:

req.header is a function, more precisely, an alias for req.get. This function exists only once inside the Express closure, therefore the statement
req.header.USERNAME = data.user.EMAIL;

in your middleware always writes to the same property, independently of the request req currently being processed. In other words: The email of user 2 overwrites the email of user 1, leading exactly to the behavior that you observe.
Write
req.USERNAME = data.user.EMAIL;

instead.

Thanks for you great help. Could you please help me with my recent question too? The backend is restarting after so many requests are processed. It runs for first half an hour without any hiccups. But then restarts.

That is a separate question, requiring perhaps different expertise (and different tags). At least I cannot help with this. Please create it as a separate question.

I created as a separate question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78835223/why-is-nodejs-express-backend-restarting-after-a-certain-number-of-requests here it is
